# Fluid resizable image with infinite horizontal scroll (REV. 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have coded a site with a simple horizontal "nowrap" css with img floated side by side. I have also hide the scrollbar away. **The side scroll can be done by normal vertical mousewheel scrolling (see my project url**

Because the images is all in big resolution of 1400x850px, i wanted to create a site that that will scale the images according to the browser size. Currently all the images are in max-width:100%, my aim is to scale them below that percentage when the browser is smaller.

I tried using max-width:100% with both width and height in auto. It not working.

I try using jquery fluid images script, they are not working as well due to "nowrap"

Below are the main code i am using:

```
#content {
width:5600px;
overflow-x: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

#portfolio img {
float:left;
display:inline;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

This is the link of my project: http://credencepartners.com/demo02/

This is the result i trying to produce (for example please see the comments): http://credencepartners.com/demo02/interface/scene01.jpg

Do i need to implement javascript on this or CSS is possible for this scenario?

---

**UPDATES / 10th Aug 2012**

Thanks to Corey for the heads up, i have updated my demo02 link. The problem now is just adding the texts below the images. I tried using a div class to combine the text and images together, the result causes the images to be be non-fluid again. Now i need help making a fluid and re-sizable div tag.

---

**GOALS**

Knowing that building a typical horizontal side scrolling website is quite straight forward. The main problem i have is only the fluid resizable images at the top. I am pretty new that fluid/responsive layout and hope the gurus here can enlighten me :)

Comment: this can be done in css. I'll whip up the code for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#portfolio {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#portfolio ul{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center; /*in case not enough images to create a scroll*/
}
#portfolio img{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
```

And lay out your html like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="portfolio">
        <ul>
            <img src="src.jpg" />
            <img src="src.jpg" />
            <img src="src.jpg" />
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Corey Thanks. It works fine for the images. Actually what i am thinking is more towards the scaling of the browser width to resize the images.

Below is the screencap of my scenario:
[link]http://credencepartners.com/demo02/interface/scene01.jpg[/link]

Realise there suppose to be a white space below. I will using fix position for the logo and navigation as well.

Comment: if you want there to be a white space, you can set the portfolio div height to a fixed pixel height instead of a percentage, or reduce the percentage from 100% to something lower. If you want a horizontal scroll, you wouldn't really need to limit the image width, but if you really want to then you can just set the max-width of "#portfolio img" in your css and change height to max-height, but this isn't advisable because you wouldn't have images the same size and other ways could cause distortion.

Comment: having looked at your comment above to @rollstuhlfahrer, you need to provide more information. Are all the images gonna be the same dimensions? It makes much more sense to limit the image height and let the width adjust automatically if the images will be of different sizes, otherwise you'll have mismatched heights and it will just look wrong, and by the screen you posted you do want to limit the height, but you can't limit the height and adjust the width based on browser size without image distortion, unless you don't mind have a percentage based portfolio div height?

Comment: Hi Corey, yep all the images will be in the same dimensions. If you look at http://cargocollective.com/runyon/cell-phone-trees , the footer is at the bottom right hand corner is in fixed position with a padding of space. That is the result i am trying to achieve. I will update my project and post here again so you can get a better idea. sorry for any confusion i have made. :)

Comment: do you mind if the page scrolls or do you want it all to perfectly fit within the window?

Comment: Hi Corey, i will like the page to fit within the window, thats the reason why i hide all the scrollbars away. Anyway i updated my project with your code. http://credencepartners.com/demo02/

Comment: Also the scrolling is horizontal and only apply for the images, The logo will be in it absolute/fixed position at the bottom. And thats the reason why i  simulate the scrolling from vertical to horizontal.

Comment: i updated my illustration and hope it provide a clearer idea: http://credencepartners.com/demo02/interface/scene01.jpg

Comment: ok cool. i'll tackle it in a couple hours for you. question: the portfolio and title will fit itself onto one page, but do you still want the page to scroll down to reveal the padding and logo in the footer? this is what the image suggests, but i just want you to clarify.

Comment: hey thanks again Corey. The logo, footer and padding will always be revealed in the browser in fixed position. Imagine the padding is a giant div container where the footer and logo are in it. i actually somehow figure it out regarding the padding (u may revisit my updated link in 1st post). Now the problem is the 'lorem text' title below each images. after i added text, the resizing no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a little and found out:

1. You need to remove the height and width-Tag from the images
2. You set the height of the "portfolio"-div to the window-height using jQuery/JavaScript

That must be all, hope I understood what you meant

Comment: Hi thanks for the tips. This is the scenario i have trying to build. http://www.credencepartners.com/demo02/interface/scene01.jpg

you can see that at the below of the images there will be some title as well as a fixed position logo. I have trying to set the standard height for the portfolio div. Not very sure about how it can be done using jquery tho.